# How to increase width of bar chart in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

How to increase width of bar chart in SSRS we also want gapping between lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. highlight the bar you want change width.
   [image]
2. go to menu View -> click properties window or press F4 button
3. in the properties window, under CustomAttributes find PointWidth and change it. if this value greater than 1, the bar will overlap. if it less than 1, it will change the width of the bar.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Select the Chart Series.  In the Properties pane, navigate to CustomAttributes / PointWidth. Adjust to suit e.g. 0.9 will produce a bar a bit wider than the default.

Comment: Hello Mike I have done this but they overlap to each other. Please also suggest to increase gap between both lines.

Comment: AFAIK the only control you have over that is the PointWidth. Your only other option is to increase the chart Area size by increasing the Chart size and/or decreasing Axis fonts.

Comment: Thanks mike but by increasing Chart size it takes lot of space and i have to use 8 charts in a page.

Answer (score 2):

If it helps, and I know this is way past the posting date, you can add an extra series, then set the series properties fill option to white. This will give the appearance of a space in between the the other columns